# Преобразовать строку в имя переменной

Tags: php

Имеется массив и переменная:

```
$array_hello = array('hello', 'world');
$array_text = "array_hello";
echo $$array_text[0]; // так не работает
```

Необходимо строку `$array_text` преобразовать в имя массива и вывести первый элемент массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP позволяет обращаться к произвольному выражению, как к имени переменной. Для этого выражение нужно обернуть в конструкцию `${...}`.

Для обращения к имени переменной, которая содержится в элементе массива, можно использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
$a = array('b');
$b = 'test';

echo ${$a[0]};
```

А для обращения к свойству объекта вот такую:

```
$a = new \StdClass();
$a->v = 'b';
$b = 'test';

echo ${$a->v};
```

В вашем же случае, вам нужно в явном виде отделить обращение к переменной от обращения к элементу массива, который в этой переменной содержится. А сделать это можно вот так:

```
$a = 'b';
$b = array('test', 'test1', 'test2');

echo ${$a}[0];
```

Comment: Вы изменили содержимое моего массива. Его менять нельзя. Нужно строку, преобразовать в имя существующего массива и затем вывести первый(или второй) элемент массива `$array_hello`.

Comment: @StasHappy, я показал вам _пример_ того, как это делается. Заменить имена переменных не составляет труда для любого, кто понимает синтаксис PHP. Если вы хотите получить код для копипаста, ждите, пока на вопрос ответит кто-то еще.

Comment: Ответ найден. Методом тыка и с помощью вашей подсказки, у меня получился вот такой вариант: `echo ${$array_text}[0];`

Comment: @StasHappy, прошу прощения, похоже я не правильно понял изначальную постановку вопроса

Comment: Дружище всё нормально. Проблему решили. Это главное.